# running app in anjuta gives me **Error**: You must have `glib' installed

Tags: c++

I get this error when I try to execute an application in anjuta in Fedora 16 and 18.

**Error**: You must have `glib' installed.

I did run 'yum install glib glib-devel' but the problem persists

I created the default C++ foobar project.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me using Fedora 18. If you double tab at glib there are multiple versions available. It seems anjuta wants version 2 as well.

```
yum install glib2-devel.x86_64
```

Figured I'd answer this since I ran into the same issue and got it to work. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora 28

```
sudo dnf install intltool
```